# How to enable the registration of users to capture an additional field with its value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have some of my #ID, that I want to save in the same table (wp_users) with the #ID that creates wordpress for the user. How can I set a sql query to be filed under the same wordpress ID. So I just want an additional field to be captured under the same wordpress ID ..

This is currently MySQL code entry for this field, ($ user_id)

```
     $sql = 'INSERT INTO wp_users (user_id) VALUES ("'.$user_id.'");';
     if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
         echo "Records inserted successfully.";
     } else{
         echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
     }
```

and this looks like a table with a moment's input ..

[image: this is how to write a new id for wp, do not put me user_id with the id that i meant for the user down (with his other data)]

[image: This is how to enter a new user but set me up for user_id null, you would like to set this value as well when you create a user]

Thank you all for help

Comment: you might want to review your title, 'shooting a new user'...

Comment: Check this may be it help you https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do if I understand well is to attach some extra data to a user (ID from another server) to be able to store and retrieve it.

You could do this with :

```
<?php get_user_meta($user_id, 'other_id', true);  ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

To retrieve the data and

```
<?php update_user_meta( $user_id, 'other_id', $your_other_id ); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

to set the data

Best

Answer (score 0):

What is that you exactly want to do ?
Basic registration form in wordpress doesn't allow additional fields than email and login.

But if you want to capture additional data with a custom form for instance, you would need to use your own `custom_register_new_user` `custom_wp_create_user` to allow pass extra data to the `wp_insert_user` function.
Ex :

```
<?php
function custom_wp_create_user($username, $password, $email = '', $firstname, $lastname) {
        $user_login = wp_slash( $username );
        $user_email = wp_slash( $email );
        $first_name = wp_slash($firstname);
        $last_name = wp_slash( $lastname );
        $user_pass = $password;

        $userdata = compact('user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass', 'first_name', 'last_name');
        return wp_insert_user($userdata);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, I want this $ user id (this is the id that I get on another server but is related to the wordpress user id) i want to get it in the database, and when the same user follows the path of the log to set me up this another ID? how is the easiest to do it? $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure to understand what you exaclty want to do.
If you want to retrieve a Wordpress user ID based on another field in the database, you may use the `wpdb` class.
Check out here [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)
Example :
`<?php
function get_user_by_user_id($user_id) {
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'users WHERE user_id = $user_id', OBJECT );
return $results;
}
?>`

Comment: this is what I want to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928515/recording-the-id-into-the-database-and-reading-the-wordpress-user-with-his-id